# What JavaScript is used on this site?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm not sure if this is an appropriate question for SO but does anyone know what jQuery library is used for the effect of the social icons at the top on this site ?http://demo.fifothemes.com/pixma/

I like how when you hover over them they slowly morph into a color.

Comment: right click > source code? lotsa css and scripts though, reading through it all could show which one is used. it could even be only in css

Comment: No Javascript, pure CSS.

Comment: You don't need a jQuery plugin for that!

Comment: The buttons don't even do anything for me.

Comment: Get off the jQuery sauce bro. There is a big world out there.

Comment: If you use browser development tools, you can examine the CSS of any element and debug scripts.

Comment: @Fresheyeball I don't understand what you mean?

Comment: @MichaelGlaz the fact that you immediately assumed it had something to do with jQuery, is a problem. jQuery and jQuery plugins have become a crutch for many developers, you should take a look at what and how much you can do without jQuery.

Comment: @Fresheyeball you should know that software development does not enter the fields of metaphysics or morality.  You had such a huge problem with my naive assumption that you had to take the time out of your precious day to admonish me for it.  Why do you care this much about the fact that jQuery is a crutch for other developers.  Why don't you just stay on your soapbox and feel superior that you're not one of those lowly developers or as ignorant as me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No Javascript: CSS transitions, example from site:

```
header .social i, footer .social i {
    color: #666;
    -webkit-transition: color .5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: color .5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: color .5s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: color .5s ease-in-out;
    transition: color .5s ease-in-out;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

They're using `transition`s (CSS) and no JS; atleast for animation.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions

However, if you need JS, then you can use jQuery and update the CSS margins of the elements by using this:

```
$('selector').css({
  margin: 'value',
  width: 'value'
})
```

And so on..

Answer (score 0):

The menu is using all CSS. 
After disabling the JS with Quick Javascript Switcher http://goo.gl/f1MeeI, all the CSS3 animations are still working.

In the OP's defense, the javascript and styles for the jQuery SuperFish Menu plugin (https://github.com/joeldbirch/superfish/) are being loaded, but the JS is unnecessary for the main navigation in this case.

[image: Chrome Developer Tools]